# Записать в массив все числа из строки через пробел C++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

Как прочитать все числа, указанные через пробел в строке Edit1 в C++ Builder?

Мой код:

```
AnsiString str, ap;
int mas[1000],i,len;
str = Edit1->Text;
len = str.Length();
for(i=1;i<=len;i++){
ap = str.Pos(' ')-1;
mas[i] = StrToInt(str.SubString(1,StrToInt(ap)));
str.Delete(1,StrToInt(str.Pos(' ')));
len= str.Length() ;
}
```

Но он криво работает.
Подскажите метод решения проблемы

Comment: В чём заключается "кривость"?

Comment: @Vlad  А индексы в AnsiString начинаются с 1 или все же с 0? И почему используется выражение ap = str.Pos(' ')-1;?

Comment: кривость заключалась в том что софт уходил в аут после считывания последнего значения

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow как ни странно но substring начинается с 0 а delete с 1

Comment: substring, delete, у всех индекс начинается с 1

Comment: [Пример](http://femils-pro.ru/2011/07/c-builder-как-разбить-строку-на-массив/)
Вот здесь нашел пример решения вашей задачки, не очень оптимальный, но рабочий. Можете проверить вариант, который я вам предложил.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так. Должно сработать. Под рукой нет билдера, могу ошибиться.

```
AnsiString str = Edit1->Text;
int mas[1000];
int posWhite;
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < str.Length(); index++)
{
    // posWhite - позиция символа, где встретился пробел(индекс начинается с 1)
    posWhite = str.Pos(' ');
    // проверка, найден ли пробел
    if(posWhite > 0)
    {
        mas[index] = StrToInt(str.SubString(1, posWhite - 1));
        str.Delete(1, posWhite));
        // увеличиваем счетчик количества обработанных символов в строке(не забываем по пробел)
        i += posWhite;
    }
    else
    {
       // делаем вывод, что все что осталось в строке, это число
       mas[index] = StrToInt(str);
       i += str.Length();      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл Решение проблемы

```
int i,j,k,m,n,l,a[1000];
str=Edit1->Text;
str=str+" ";
l=str.Length();
k=0;
for(i=1;i<=l;i++){
  j = str.Pos(' ')-1;
  a[i-1]=StrToInt(str.SubString(1,j));
  str.Delete(1,j+1);
  l-=j;
  k++;
}
```

Comment: Зачем нужна переменная k?